# Class Path & Resource files

Tags: java, file, resources

If I have a resource file (wsdl file) in the class path, should I recompile my java app if I changed something in this wsdl file (the target address location)? or I can change the wsdl file without recompiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just using it as a text resource, you do not have to recompile it.

You *will* want to recompile/repackage it if:

- You're using the WSDL to generate some of your java classes (common with API frameworks)
- You're packaging the classes/resources into an archive (jar, war)